# Using Coldfusion DateDiff within a MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, datediff

I've spent a few hours playing around with this one, without success so far.

I'm outputting a very large query, and trying to split it into chunks before processing the data.  This query will basically run every day, and one of the fields ('last_checked') will be used to ensure the same data isn't processed more than once a day.

Here's my existing query;

```
<cfquery name="getprice" maxrows="100">
  SELECT ID, source, last_checked, price
  FROM product_prices
  WHERE source='api'
  ORDER BY ID ASC
</cfquery>
```

I then run a cfoutput query on the results to do various updates.  The table currently holds just over 100,000 records and is starting to struggle to process everything in one hit, hence the need to split it into chunks.

My intention is to cfschedule it to run every so often (I'll increase the maxrows and probably have it run every 15 minutes, for example).  However, I need it to only return results that haven't been updated within the last 24 hours - this is where I'm getting stuck.

I know MySQL has it's own DateDiff and TimeDiff functions, but I don't seem to be able to grasp the syntax for that - if indeed its applicable for my use (docs seem to contradict themselves in that regard - or, at the least the ones I've read).

Any pointers very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with MySQL first:

```
SELECT ID, source, last_checked, price
  FROM product_prices
  WHERE source='api'
      AND last_checked >= current_timestamp - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
  ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I've pasted that in exactly as you typed, but it's giving me a syntax error.  I've never come across INTERVAL before, and the only examples I can find related to creating events, so I'm at a loss where to start!

Comment: Try changing it to HOUR instead of HOURS

Comment: Thanks Eric & JakeFeasel - I've got it working perfectly now.  Much appreciated to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

I would caution you against using `maxrows=100` in your cfquery.  This will still return the full recordset to CF from the database, and only then will CF filter out all but the first 100 rows.  When you are dealing with a 100,000 row dataset, then this is going to be hugely expensive.  Presumably, your filter for only the last 24 hours will dramatically reduce the size of your base result set, so perhaps this won't really be a big problem.  However, if you find that even by limiting your set to those changed within the last 24 hours you still have a very large set of records to work with, you could change the way you do this to work much more efficiently.  Instead of using CF to filter your results, have MySQL do it using the LIMIT  keyword in your query:

```
SELECT ID, source, last_checked, price
  FROM product_prices
  WHERE source='api'
      AND last_checked >= current_timestamp - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ORDER BY ID ASC
LIMIT 0,100
```

You could also easily set between "pages" of 100 rows by adding the offset value before the LIMIT: `LIMIT 300, 100` would be rows 300-400 from your result set.  Doing the paging this way will be much faster than offloading it to CF.

Comment: Thanks Jake, very good point - I really should use LIMIT more often!